# Is this question acceptable?

Tags: support, scope

Was the damage that BP paid for the damage in Mexican Gulf the largest amount ever paid for a damage? What was the second largest amount?

Answer (score 2):

This is not generally considered a "good" Stack Exchange question because:

1. The answer to the first is a simple "No."
2. The answer to the second is likely to become quickly obsolete.
3. It's just [a simple web search](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=largest+judgments).  (And especially [the BP settlement appears explicitly in the top three results without even being included as a search term](http://www.nola.com/crime/index.ssf/2015/07/the_10_most_expensive_court_ju.html#0).)